# How to create tabs based on observablearray using jqueryui-tabs

Tags: javascript, knockout.js, jquery-ui-tabs

I am trying to create a tab structure using jqueryui - tabs.

As per the documentation, we can hardcode number of tabs in html we want and give href in anchor tag for each "li" tag.That way everything is working fine.

But what I need is different. I am retrieving some data from server. Based on the length of the data I want to show number of tabs( that I am trying to do using foreach binding). I am able to create tabs, but it is not working without an "href" property.

```js
this.tabList = ko.observableArray(
  [
    {tbna: "abc"},
    {tbna:'1234'}
  ]);

$( "#tabs" ).tabs();

this.retrieveData = function()
{
 //Do stuff here on click
 }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.2.0/knockout-min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="tabs" style="font-size: 14px;">
    <ul data-bind="foreach : tabList">
       
       <li><a data-bind="text : $data.tbna, click: $parent.retrieveData"></a></li>
    
    </ul>
  </div>
```

Anybody has any idea, how I can do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need custom binding handlers for widgets. Binding handlers are what tell Knockout how to synchronize the DOM and your model. Knockout doesn't know about jQuery UI's tabs widget, and it doesn't know about your viewmodel. Fortunately, a lot of binding handlers for common widgets have been written. [Here's one for tabs](http://gvas.github.io/knockout-jqueryui/tabs.html).

Comment: Thanks for the answer. This helped.